# How can I fix the tabbing order of my accordion tile menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accessibility

I am creating a tiles/accordion utility. 
On click of a tile, I am going to display the content relevant to that tile by appending the div content below the nearest third li element and will manually set focus to that div content section.

I am able to achieve this functionality now with help of JS and CSS:

[image]

However, the accessibility/tab order functionality is screwed up. If I click on Tile 1 and the content is displayed for it (the div will be appended below the third li element), on tabbing using keyboard, after the link the focus should go to Tile 2, but it goes to Tile 4 (since the ordering of elements in the DOM is in that order and I have relatively positioned the elements in different order for display).

If I remove relative positioning for the elements, the look gets screwed up.

Possible solution through which I feel that can be fixed:

1. Removing relative positioning of elements and on every click of tile, calculate top, left position values and relatively re-align the positions of the tiles.
2. Using keyboard events, force the focus in the order that is needed.

Does anyone have any suggestions for easy solution for this?

Correct tabbing order:

1. If Tile 1 was clicked,

   - First tab - Focus on Link inside div.
   - Second tab - Focus should move to Tile 2.
   - Third tab - Focus should move to Tile 3.
   - Fourth tab - Focus should move to Tile 4.
2. If Tile 2 was clicked,

   - First tab - Focus on Link inside div.
   - Second tab - Focus should move to Tile.
   - Third tab - Focus should move to Tile.
   - Fourth tab - Focus should move to Tile

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tiles > li").click(function() {
        var idVal = $(this).find("a").attr("rel");

        dynamicContainerClass = "";

        var indexVal = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        $(".dynamicContainer").remove();

        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        var $positionObj = $("#contentDiv").html();

        //$('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))

        if (indexVal % 3 == 1) {
            var next = $(this).next();
            var nextCtr = 1;
            while (next.hasClass("active") == false) {
                next = next.next();
                nextCtr++;
                if (nextCtr > 12) {
                    break
                }
            }
            var afterNext = next.next();
            var afterNextCtr = 1;
            while (afterNext.hasClass("active") == false) {
                afterNext = afterNext.next();
                afterNextCtr++;
                if (afterNextCtr > 12) {
                    break
                }
            }
            if (afterNext.size() > 0) {
                $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter(afterNext)
            } else {
                if (next.size() > 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter(next)
                } else {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (indexVal % 3 == 2) {
                var nextCtr = 1;
                var next = $(this).next();
                while (next.hasClass("active") == false) {
                    next = next.next();
                    nextCtr++;
                    if (nextCtr > 12) {
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (next.size() > 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter(next)
                } else {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            } else {
                if (indexVal % 3 == 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            }
        }

        $(".dynamicContainer #" + id).addClass("container-text").attr("tabindex", "-1").focus();

    });

});
```

```css
.tiles-module {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    width: 292px;
    background-color: #e5e2da;
    margin: 0 10px;
    min-height: 1px;
}

.tiles-module .tiles-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 16px;
    color: #6b5e51;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.tiles-module #tiles>li {
    float: left;
    width: 95px;
    height: 89px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.tiles-module img {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container li a {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: medium none;
    color: #605952;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 85px;
    outline: medium none;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    width: 91px;
    border-right: 2px solid #b6b5b2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b6b5b2;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container {
    margin-left: 4px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.tiles-module .dynamicContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container .container-text {
    width: 284px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.tiles-module .container-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 268px;
}

.container-text {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container li a:focus, .tiles-module .tab-container li a:active {
    background-color: #B0E9FD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="tiles-module">
        <div class="tiles-tab">
            <div class="tab-container">
                <div class="tiles-header">
                    <h3>Tiles Section</h3>
                </div>
                <ul id="tiles">
                    <li class="active" rel="1">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
                            <p>Tile 1</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="2">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
                            <p>Tile 2</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="3">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 3</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="4">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 4</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="5">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 5</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="6">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 6 </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="7">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 7 </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="active" rel="8">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 8</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ClearAll" style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentDiv" style="display:none;">This is the tile content <a href="javascript:void(0);">This is link focusable element inside tile content</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code - https://jsbin.com/rezehepuju/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Hi, please do not circumvent the requirements in the big red banner you saw by posting a link as "code". Include your code here in the question itself (see [mcve] for more info).

Comment: Code is included now.

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, try to **avoid** using `tabindex`.  If the tiles were the only thing on your page, then messing with `tabindex` might be ok.  But once you set the `tabindex` of one object, you have to set it for **all** objects.  That is, you have to completely control the tab order of everything on the page.  It gets messy very fast.

The DOM order of tabbing is usually the best order, so if you have to change the tab order, it's usually best to change your DOM.

However, keep in mind that low vision users, especially ones that use magnifiers such as ZoomText, might get confused on your tab order because it won't be consistent.  Magnifiers will scroll the page to keep the focus  within view.

If tile 1 is open, then the order is:

1. tile 1
2. link
3. tile 2
4. tile 3

If tile 2 is open, then the order is:

1. tile 1
2. tile 2
3. link
4. tile 3

If tile 3 is open, then the order is:

1. tile 1
2. tile 2
3. tile 3
4. link

A screen magnifier will be constantly moving back and forth in a "seemingly" random way.  The user won't know if the focus is going to move across the tiles before jumping down to an open section.

That doesn't answer your original question (although `tabindex` is sort of an answer), but hopefully gives some food for thought from an accessibility perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to achieve the intended tabbing order by using this solution. Re positioning the tiles using absolute, top, left properties. It worked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#tiles > li").click(function() {
        var idVal = $(this).find("a").attr("rel");

        dynamicContainerClass = "";

        var indexVal = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        $(".dynamicContainer").remove();

        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        var $positionObj = $("#contentDiv").html();

        var listItems = $("#tiles li");
        listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
      $(li).css({'position':'','top':'','left':''});
        });

        //$('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))

        if (indexVal % 3 == 1) {
            var next = $(this).next();
            var positionOne = next.position();
            var nextCtr = 1;
            while (next.hasClass("active") == false) {
                next = next.next();
                nextCtr++;
                if (nextCtr > 12) {
                    break
                }
            }
            var afterNext = next.next();
            var positionTwo = afterNext.position();
            var afterNextCtr = 1;
            while (afterNext.hasClass("active") == false) {
                afterNext = afterNext.next();
                afterNextCtr++;
                if (afterNextCtr > 12) {
                    break
                }
            }
            if (afterNext.size() > 0) {
                $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this));
               afterNext.css('position','absolute');
         afterNext.css('left',positionTwo.left);
         afterNext.css('top',positionTwo.top);
         next.css('position','absolute');
         next.css('left',positionOne.left);
         next.css('top',positionOne.top);
            } else {
                if (next.size() > 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this));
                    next.css('position','absolute');
              next.css('left',positionOne.left);
              next.css('top',positionOne.top);
                } else {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (indexVal % 3 == 2) {
                var nextCtr = 1;
                var next = $(this).next();
                var positionOne = next.position();
                while (next.hasClass("active") == false) {
                    next = next.next();
                    nextCtr++;
                    if (nextCtr > 12) {
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (next.size() > 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this));
                    next.css('position','absolute');
              next.css('left',positionOne.left);
              next.css('top',positionOne.top);
                } else {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            } else {
                if (indexVal % 3 == 0) {
                    $('<div class=dynamicContainer aria-live="assertive" tabindex="-1"><div id=' + id + " class=" + dynamicContainerClass + ">" + $positionObj + "</div></div>").insertAfter($(this))
                }
            }
        }

        $(".dynamicContainer #" + id).addClass("container-text").attr("tabindex", "-1").focus();

    });

});
```

```css
.tiles-module {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: block;
    width: 292px;
    background-color: #e5e2da;
    margin: 0 10px;
    min-height: 1px;
}

.tiles-module .tiles-header {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 1px 16px;
    color: #6b5e51;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.tiles-module #tiles>li {
    float: left;
    width: 95px;
    height: 89px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}

.tiles-module img {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container li a {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: medium none;
    color: #605952;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 85px;
    outline: medium none;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    width: 91px;
    border-right: 2px solid #b6b5b2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #b6b5b2;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container {
    margin-left: 4px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.tiles-module .dynamicContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container .container-text {
    width: 284px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.tiles-module .container-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 268px;
}

.container-text {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tiles-module .tab-container li a:focus, .tiles-module .tab-container li a:active {
    background-color: #B0E9FD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="tiles-module">
        <div class="tiles-tab">
            <div class="tab-container">
                <div class="tiles-header">
                    <h3>Tiles Section</h3>
                </div>
                <ul id="tiles">
                    <li class="active" rel="1">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
                            <p>Tile 1</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="2">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
                            <p>Tile 2</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="3">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 3</p></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="4">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 4</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="5">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 5</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="6">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 6 </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active" rel="7">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 7 </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="active" rel="8">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                            <p>Tile 8</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ClearAll" style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentDiv" style="display:none;">This is the tile content <a href="javascript:void(0);">This is link focusable element inside tile content</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```